# Node.js it prints the same result twice, instead of once

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

This is my node.js application code:

This is my html.js file code

```
    /**
 * HTML Helpers
 */
'use strict';

var cheerio = require('cheerio');


module.exports.gotHTML = function gotHTML(error, response, htmlBody) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

        const $ = cheerio.load(htmlBody);

        var reviews = [];
        var businesses = [];
        var combinedData;
        var reviewsSelectors = $('.js-hot-new-businesses-section .rating-qualifier');
        var businessSelectors = $('.js-hot-new-businesses-section .biz-name');

        reviewsSelectors.each(function (index, value) {
            reviews.push($(this).text().trim());
        });

        businessSelectors.each(function (index, value) {
            businesses.push($(this).text().trim())
        });

        combinedData = businesses.map(function (value, index) {
            return {businessName: value, reviewsTotal: reviews[index]};
        });

        combinedData.forEach(function(value, index) {
            console.log(value["businessName"] + " - " + value["reviewsTotal"]);
        })

    }
}
```

And this one is the app.js file code

```
    'use strict';

const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const htmlHelpers = require('./html');


const url = 'https://www.yelp.com/sf';

request(url, htmlHelpers.gotHTML);


// Expose app
exports = module.exports = app;
```

And when I execute this code,in order to print the name and number of reviews of the first result once it prints those twice. This is the output

```
Boba Guys - 24 reviews
Boba Guys - 24 reviews
Coletta Gelato - 23 reviews
Coletta Gelato - 23 reviews
An Chi - 29 reviews
An Chi - 29 reviews
```

By the way the same code properly executes and prints the desired results in the browser console.

```
Boba Guys - 24 reviews
Coletta Gelato - 23 reviews
An Chi - 29 reviews
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because cheerio does not execute the scripts from the page  while a browser does. Cheerio cares only about HTML.

Take a look at the response you're getting.

```html
<div class="home-container_section js-hot-new-businesses-section">
 <h3 class="explore-city_title">Hot & New Businesses</h3>
 <div class="arrange arrange--wrap arrange--3-units arrange--30">
  <div class="arrange_unit">
   <div class="card business-passport-card">
    <div class="card_photo">

     <div class="photo-box photo-box--interactive photo-box--background" style="background-image: url(https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/OA40TlIfaVARVjRdZnB0SA/l.jpg)">
      <a href="/biz/coletta-gelato-san-francisco" class="photo-box_link js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-photo">
       <img alt="Coletta Gelato" class="photo-box-img" height="400" src="https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/OA40TlIfaVARVjRdZnB0SA/l.jpg" width="600">

      </a>

     </div>

    </div>
    <div class="card_body">
     <div class="card_content">
      <h3 class="card_content-title--linked u-text-truncate">

       <div class="business-link-hovercard js-business-link-hovercard">
        <span class="business-link-hovercard_business-link js-business-link">
                    <a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/coletta-gelato-san-francisco" data-hovercard-id="" ><span >Coletta Gelato</span></a>

        </span>
        <div class="business-link-hovercard_hovercard u-hidden u-break-word js-business-hovercard">
         <div class="media-block media-block--12 biz-listing-medium">
          <div class="media-avatar">
           <div class="photo-box pb-90s">
            <a href="/biz/coletta-gelato-san-francisco" class="js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-photo">
             <img alt="Coletta Gelato" class="photo-box-img" height="90" src="https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/OA40TlIfaVARVjRdZnB0SA/90s.jpg" width="90">

            </a>

           </div>



          </div>
          <div class="media-story">
           <div class="media-title clearfix">
            <a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/coletta-gelato-san-francisco" data-hovercard-id="" ><span >Coletta Gelato</span></a>

           </div>
           <div class="biz-rating biz-rating-large clearfix" itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">



            <div class="i-stars i-stars--regular-5 rating-large" title="5.0 star rating">
             <img class="offscreen" height="303" src="https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/srv0/yelp_design_web/41341496d9db/assets/img/stars/stars.png" width="84" alt="5.0 star rating">
            </div>
            <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="5.0">


            <span class="review-count rating-qualifier">
            <span itemprop="reviewCount">25</span> reviews
    </span>

           </div>

           <div class="price-category">
                <span class="bullet-after">
            
        <span class="business-attribute price-range">$$</span>
        </span>
            <span class="category-str-list">
                    Gelato,
                    Ice Cream &amp; Frozen Yogurt
    </span>


           </div>

           <small>
            <span class="addr-city">San Francisco, CA</span>

           </small>

          </div>
         </div>

        </div>
       </div>

      </h3>
      <div class="biz-rating biz-rating-large clearfix" >



       <div class="i-stars i-stars--regular-5 rating-large" title="5.0 star rating">
        <img class="offscreen" height="303" src="https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/srv0/yelp_design_web/41341496d9db/assets/img/stars/stars.png" width="84" alt="5.0 star rating">
       </div>


       <span class="review-count rating-qualifier">
            25 reviews
    </span>

      </div>

      <div class="price-category">
                <span class="bullet-after">
            
        <span class="business-attribute price-range">$$</span>
        </span>
       <span class="category-str-list">
                    Gelato,
                    Ice Cream &amp; Frozen Yogurt
    </span>


      </div>

      <p class="business-passport-card_date-opened">
            <span aria-hidden="true" style="width: 18px; height: 18px;" class="icon icon--18-flame icon--size-18 icon--currentColor">
    <svg class="icon_svg">
        <use xlink:href="#18x18_flame" />
    </svg>
</span> Opened 6 weeks ago
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

  </div>
  <div class="arrange_unit">
   <div class="card business-passport-card">
    <div class="card_photo">

     <div class="photo-box photo-box--interactive photo-box--background" style="background-image: url(https://s3-media3.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/teafIvqzpXkxVidRzpkJOQ/l.jpg)">
      <a href="/biz/food-la-la-san-francisco" class="photo-box_link js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-photo">
       <img alt="Food La La" class="photo-box-img" height="400" src="https://s3-media3.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/teafIvqzpXkxVidRzpkJOQ/l.jpg" width="600">

      </a>

     </div>

    </div>
    <div class="card_body">
     <div class="card_content">
      <h3 class="card_content-title--linked u-text-truncate">

       <div class="business-link-hovercard js-business-link-hovercard">
        <span class="business-link-hovercard_business-link js-business-link">
                    <a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/food-la-la-san-francisco" data-hovercard-id="" ><span >Food La La</span></a>

        </span>
        <div class="business-link-hovercard_hovercard u-hidden u-break-word js-business-hovercard">
         <div class="media-block media-block--12 biz-listing-medium">
          <div class="media-avatar">
           <div class="photo-box pb-90s">
            <a href="/biz/food-la-la-san-francisco" class="js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-photo">
             <img alt="Food La La" class="photo-box-img" height="90" src="https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/teafIvqzpXkxVidRzpkJOQ/90s.jpg" width="90">

            </a>

           </div>



          </div>
          <div class="media-story">
           <div class="media-title clearfix">
            <a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/food-la-la-san-francisco" data-hovercard-id="" ><span >Food La La</span></a>

           </div>
           <div class="biz-rating biz-rating-large clearfix" itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">



            <div class="i-stars i-stars--regular-5 rating-large" title="5.0 star rating">
             <img class="offscreen" height="303" src="https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/srv0/yelp_design_web/41341496d9db/assets/img/stars/stars.png" width="84" alt="5.0 star rating">
            </div>
            <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="5.0">


            <span class="review-count rating-qualifier">
            <span itemprop="reviewCount">10</span> reviews
    </span>

           </div>

           <div class="price-category">
                <span class="bullet-after">
            
        <span class="business-attribute price-range">$$</span>
        </span>
            <span class="category-str-list">
                    Cooking Classes
    </span>


           </div>

           <small>
            <span class="addr-city">San Francisco, CA</span>

           </small>

          </div>
         </div>

        </div>
       </div>

      </h3>
      <div class="biz-rating biz-rating-large clearfix" >



       <div class="i-stars i-stars--regular-5 rating-large" title="5.0 star rating">
        <img class="offscreen" height="303" src="https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/srv0/yelp_design_web/41341496d9db/assets/img/stars/stars.png" width="84" alt="5.0 star rating">
       </div>


       <span class="review-count rating-qualifier">
            10 reviews
    </span>

      </div>

      <div class="price-category">
                <span class="bullet-after">
            
        <span class="business-attribute price-range">$$</span>
        </span>
       <span class="category-str-list">
                    Cooking Classes
    </span>


      </div>

      <p class="business-passport-card_date-opened">
            <span aria-hidden="true" style="width: 18px; height: 18px;" class="icon icon--18-flame icon--size-18 icon--currentColor">
    <svg class="icon_svg">
        <use xlink:href="#18x18_flame" />
    </svg>
</span> Opened 4 weeks ago
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

  </div>
  <div class="arrange_unit">
   <div class="card business-passport-card">
    <div class="card_photo">

     <div class="photo-box photo-box--interactive photo-box--background" style="background-image: url(https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/MkwY_oo9oz0CYITBrfqtbA/l.jpg)">
      <a href="/biz/saltroot-cafe-san-francisco" class="photo-box_link js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-photo">
       <img alt="Saltroot Cafe" class="photo-box-img" height="400" src="https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/MkwY_oo9oz0CYITBrfqtbA/l.jpg" width="600">

      </a>

     </div>

    </div>
    <div class="card_body">
     <div class="card_content">
      <h3 class="card_content-title--linked u-text-truncate">

       <div class="business-link-hovercard js-business-link-hovercard">
        <span class="business-link-hovercard_business-link js-business-link">
                    <a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/saltroot-cafe-san-francisco" data-hovercard-id="" ><span >Saltroot Cafe</span></a>

        </span>
        <div class="business-link-hovercard_hovercard u-hidden u-break-word js-business-hovercard">
         <div class="media-block media-block--12 biz-listing-medium">
          <div class="media-avatar">
           <div class="photo-box pb-90s">
            <a href="/biz/saltroot-cafe-san-francisco" class="js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-photo">
             <img alt="Saltroot Cafe" class="photo-box-img" height="90" src="https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/MkwY_oo9oz0CYITBrfqtbA/90s.jpg" width="90">

            </a>

           </div>



          </div>
          <div class="media-story">
           <div class="media-title clearfix">
            <a class="biz-name js-analytics-click" data-analytics-label="biz-name" href="/biz/saltroot-cafe-san-francisco" data-hovercard-id="" ><span >Saltroot Cafe</span></a>

           </div>
           <div class="biz-rating biz-rating-large clearfix" itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">



            <div class="i-stars i-stars--regular-5 rating-large" title="5.0 star rating">
             <img class="offscreen" height="303" src="https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/srv0/yelp_design_web/41341496d9db/assets/img/stars/stars.png" width="84" alt="5.0 star rating">
            </div>
            <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="5.0">


            <span class="review-count rating-qualifier">
            <span itemprop="reviewCount">11</span> reviews
    </span>

           </div>

           <div class="price-category">
                <span class="bullet-after">
            
        <span class="business-attribute price-range">$</span>
        </span>
            <span class="category-str-list">
                    Bakeries,
                    Coffee &amp; Tea
    </span>


           </div>

           <small>
            <span class="addr-city">San Francisco, CA</span>

           </small>

          </div>
         </div>

        </div>
       </div>

      </h3>
      <div class="biz-rating biz-rating-large clearfix" >



       <div class="i-stars i-stars--regular-5 rating-large" title="5.0 star rating">
        <img class="offscreen" height="303" src="https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/assets/srv0/yelp_design_web/41341496d9db/assets/img/stars/stars.png" width="84" alt="5.0 star rating">
       </div>


       <span class="review-count rating-qualifier">
            11 reviews
    </span>

      </div>

      <div class="price-category">
                <span class="bullet-after">
            
        <span class="business-attribute price-range">$</span>
        </span>
       <span class="category-str-list">
                    Bakeries,
                    Coffee &amp; Tea
    </span>


      </div>

      <p class="business-passport-card_date-opened">
            <span aria-hidden="true" style="width: 18px; height: 18px;" class="icon icon--18-flame icon--size-18 icon--currentColor">
    <svg class="icon_svg">
        <use xlink:href="#18x18_flame" />
    </svg>
</span> Opened 3 weeks ago
      </p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="u-space-t2 u-text-centered">
  <a class="js-analytics-click explore-city_see-all" data-analytics-label="link-more" href="/search?attrs=NewBusiness" >See more hot and new businesses</a>
 </div>

</div>
```

Run the above snippet here or [launch the page](http://jsbin.com/vuqeviqova/1/edit?html,output) at jsbin.com and you'll see that originally blocks that you are interested in are duplicated. Then JS cuts the duplicates and as I understand shows them on hover (as hover cards).

```html
//As you remember there are duplicates for each of the element, you're looking for.
//Here are the parent element's classes (the whole tree)
//So you can see the difference, and make the selectors you want

Raiting qualifiers:
"home-container_section js-hot-new-businesses-section" > "arrange arrange--wrap arrange--3-units arrange--30" > "arrange_unit" > "card business-passport-card" > "card_body" > "card_content" > "card_content-title--linked u-text-truncate" > "business-link-hovercard js-business-link-hovercard" > "business-link-hovercard_hovercard u-hidden u-break-word js-business-hovercard" > "media-block media-block--12 biz-listing-medium" > "media-story" > "biz-rating biz-rating-large clearfix" > "review-count rating-qualifier"
"home-container_section js-hot-new-businesses-section" > "arrange arrange--wrap arrange--3-units arrange--30" > "arrange_unit" > "card business-passport-card" > "card_body" > "card_content" > "biz-rating biz-rating-large clearfix" > "review-count rating-qualifier"

Biz names:
"home-container_section js-hot-new-businesses-section" > "arrange arrange--wrap arrange--3-units arrange--30" > "arrange_unit" > "card business-passport-card" > "card_body" > "card_content" > "card_content-title--linked u-text-truncate" > "business-link-hovercard js-business-link-hovercard" > "business-link-hovercard_business-link js-business-link" > "biz-name js-analytics-click"
"home-container_section js-hot-new-businesses-section" > "arrange arrange--wrap arrange--3-units arrange--30" > "arrange_unit" > "card business-passport-card" > "card_body" > "card_content" > "card_content-title--linked u-text-truncate" > "business-link-hovercard js-business-link-hovercard" > "business-link-hovercard_hovercard u-hidden u-break-word js-business-hovercard" > "media-block media-block--12 biz-listing-medium" > "media-story" > "media-title clearfix" > "biz-name js-analytics-click"
```

To solve your problem simply be more specific e.g. like this depending on which elements you need:

```js
var reviewsSelectors = $('.js-hot-new-businesses-section .media-story .rating-qualifier');
var businessSelectors = $('.js-hot-new-businesses-section .js-business-link .biz-name');
```

Comment: Dear Antonio, I respect your attention to my question, but according to your version it prints once, but it takes another content, not those I want.

Comment: @HaykMkhitaryan I have updated the answer. Now you have the class-names of all parent element and you can build the selectors you need.